# How to move qwidget on Graphics View?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

On a `QGraphicsView` I set a `QGraphicsScene`. I add a `QDial` object through a `QGraphicsProxy` widget. How to move the `QDial` object?

```
    QDial *dial = new QDial;// dial object
    dial->setGeometry(event->pos().x(),event->pos().y(),80,80);// placing on mouse position
    QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(dial);

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(dial);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);

    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
    proxy->setWidget(dial);
    proxy->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable,true);
    scene->addItem(proxy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code QGraphicsWidget is GraphicItem by making parent of widget you can move widget on scene.setflags movable.

```
   QDial *dial = new QDial;// dial object
   dial->setGeometry(event->pos().x(),event->pos().y(),80,80);// placing on mouse position
   QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(dial);

   QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(dial);
   layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
   layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);

   QGraphicsWidget* parentWidget = new QGraphicsWidget();//make parent of widget
   parentWidget->setCursor(Qt::SizeAllCursor);
   parentWidget->setGeometry(event->scenePos().x(),event->scenePos().y(),width.toInt(), height.toInt());
   parentWidget->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable );
   addItem(parentWidget);

   QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
   proxy->setWidget(dial);
   proxy->setParentItem(parentWidget);
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting the `QDial` into a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` is only the first step.

Since the proxy does not support moving, you can put it into a `QGraphicsItem` (e.g. a rect) and use this to move the proxy with the `QDial` in it:

```
QDial *dial = new QDial();

QGraphicsRectItem* movableGraphicsItem = scene->addRect(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y(), 80, 80);
movableGraphicsItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
movableGraphicsItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);

QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxy = scene->addWidget(dial);
proxy->setPos(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y() + movableGraphicsItem->rect().height());
proxy->setParentItem(movableGraphicsItem);

movableGraphicsItem->setRotation(180); // Test by rotating the graphics item
```

I have not tested this, you may have to play around with the sizing, the position and the layout and size grip you are using, but this is the base from where you can start.

Comment: thanks ... i am resizing rect item...i thought  rect item is parent  so that  dial will automatic resize but its not happening.